# Get latest record for each category with Rails or SQL

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm new to SQL & I'm trying to get the `id` for each **category** with the latest `offer_valid_till`. Below is my database structure.

| id | category_id | offer_valid_till |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | NULL |
| 2 | 2 | Sat, 23 Sep 2023 06:47:07 UTC +00:00 |
| 3 | 1 | Sun, 12 Jun 2022 09:55:53 UTC +00:00 |
| 4 | 3 | Tue, 12 Apr 2022 08:55:51 UTC +00:00 |
| 5 | 4 | NULL |
| 6 | 3 | Wed, 16 Nov 2021 03:18:10 UTC +00:00 |

---

**Expected response:**

| category_id | id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 4 | 5 |

---

**Here is what I tried:**

```
SELECT MAX(offer_valid_till), id
FROM OFFERS
GROUP BY category_id, id
HAVING MAX(offer_valid_till) = offer_valid_till
```

Any **Rails** or **SQL** solution will be a great help. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this code :

```
select category_id,id from (
    SELECT *
           ,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by category_id order by offer_valid_till desc  ) as rn
    FROM OFFERS)a 
where rn=1
```

This query set numbers the offer_valid_till field in order. Then it extracts the first value from each category.